# touchpad's click isn't working on Arch installation with Gnome

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, touchpad

The touchpad's click isn't working(doesn't click when tapped) on my Arch installation with Gnome; I've already installed `xf86-input-synaptics`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System>>Mouse and enable "Click through touchpad"

Answer (score 6):

```
synclient TapButton1=1
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

After recent upgrades to X, you may need to move some of the relevant sections in your xorg.conf into xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf.

There is [a thread on the Arch boards](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=115196) that details the issue.

Comment: problem solved. turns out the problem is much simpler- System>>Mouse and you enable click through touchpad :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome 3:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```